# WSO2 Api Manager : admin using Log Analyzer (Analytics server Not Found)

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Need Help guys,

when i'm trying to configure and use LOG Analyzer at Api Manager : Admin, it's said "Analytics server not found."
what do i miss? because i already configure Api Manager Analytics.

thanks

Images :

https://www.pastepic.xyz/image/image.6ZANC

https://ibb.co/tqwrVfs

Comment: means analytics not activated

Comment: @daggett i already running APIM analytics, which config i should need to check it out?

Comment: check, that you are running `worker` from analytics. if you run all locally then just edit `api-manager.xml` find there `<Analytics>` and set `<Enabled>true</Enabled>`